# Is the set of symmetric positive semi-definite matrices a smooth manifold with boundary

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $P_n(\mathbb{R}):=\left\{
A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}):\,
A=A^T \mbox{ and }  (\forall i)\,
\lambda_i^A \geq 0
\right\}$, where $\left\{\lambda_i^A\right\}_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.  Is this a manifold with boundary which can be decomposed as:
$$
P_n(\mathbb{R}) = P_n^+(\mathbb{R}) \cup Sym_n^0(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $Sym_n^0(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices satisfying $x^TAx=0$ for some non-zero vector and $P_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of symmetric positive-definite matrices with real entries?

I know that $P_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth manifold since I can explicitly write down its global chart using the matrix exponential map and (a slight variant of) the [vectorization operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).  However, I'm not sure if $Sym_n^0(\mathbb{R})$ is of dimension $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} -1$.

Comment: If the determinant of an nxn matrix is positive, it is not 0, so the rank r must be equal to n.

Comment: I had made a mistake with my computation, the correct object is now posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An explicit calculation shows that when $n = 2$, the set $\textrm{Sym}^0_n(\mathbb{R})$ is given by

$$ \textrm{Sym}^0_2(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}  \, \bigg\rvert \,  ac - b^2 = 0, a + c \geq 0 \right\}. $$

Performing the change of variables
$$ a = z - x, b = y, c = z + x $$
this set transforms into

$$ \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} z - x & y \\ y & z - x \end{pmatrix} \, \bigg\rvert \, z^2 = x^2 + y^2, z \geq 0 \right \}. $$

The equation $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ is the equation of a double cone and the condition $z \geq 0$ gives us a single cone with singularity at the origin:

[image]

This shows that $\textrm{Sym}^0_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not a manifold and so $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not a manifold with boundary. However, if you look at the sets $S_r$ which consist of symmetric positive semi-definite matrices of rank $r$ for $0 \leq r \leq n$ then each one of those is a submanifold and the whole space of positive semi-definine matrices can be given the structure of a stratified space with strata $S_r$.

Comment: Fantastic answer honestly!  Actually on that point...Does $S_r$ admit an explicit global homeomorphism to some Euclidean space?

Comment: @AIM_BLB: Thanks. I'm not sure what you're asking: The top strata $S_n$ is naturally an open subset of the vector subspace of symmetric matrices. For the other strata, you can write them globally as zeroes of polynomial equations, you can write them locally as a level set of a regular value or construct explicit local parametrizations using some of the entries of the matrix as parameters.

Comment: @Ievap *I have a key question (after thinking a while on this answer):* You show that $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ isn't a smooth manifold, but if I'm not mistaken your argument does show that it is a *topological* manifold with corners?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AIM_BLB: I'm not sure what you mean. There is no notion of "topological manifold with corners" that I'm familiar with (as the topology does not "detect" the corners, only boundary) and in any case the cone is at best considered a "singular manifold".

Comment: Right, this makes sense.  Also when you say stratified space this means something like $P_n = \sqcup_r S_r$ where $\sqcup$ is the topological disjoint union?